# What is the difference between deleting and clearing downloads?

Tags: downloading

If I select on a download I am given the option to delete or clear the selection. What is the difference? If I select clear, do it mean I still have the option to delete? If so where from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearing downloads will only clear it from the *list of downloads.*

To delete files that have been cleared from the list, you would need to do so directly from the SD card's download folder, either with your computer or using a file manager like [Astro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en).